# Find the correct word by incrementing letters in alphabet

Tags: javascript

Hi I came acroos this challenge from jschallenger page. I write the following code and It's working Fine unless any capital letter is passed. It seems to me ltr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" is not the right way. Could you please tell how can I improve my code?

```
function myf(a){
 let ltr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 let newstr =""

for(i=0; i<=a.split("").length-1; i++){
    let str = ltr.indexOf(a.charAt(i))+1
    
    let mystr = ltr.charAt(str )
    newstr += mystr
    }

 console.log(newstr)
}

myf("bnchm")  // result: coding
myf("bgddrd") // result: cheese
myf("sdrshmf")// result:testing
```

Comment: It's one way to do it, working with character codes is another (look up ASCII table as a useful learning point). Your implementation could be made to work with caps - but capital letters are different, with different character codes under the hood. If you simply append the capitals to your `ltr` string ( i.e. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDE...`) it will _start_ to work, however you'll need to think about what happens when it encounters a lowercase Z (it will incorrectly change to a capital A, not lowercase), capital Z (you'll need to think how to wrap back around to uppercase A), numbers...

Comment: And one point - seeing as you are not modifying you `ltr` variable - it's a reference constant - it is good practice to declare as `const` instead. And your `i` iterator variable needs a `let` keyword in front of it as well :)

Comment: So, why don't you ignore the case? ```a.toLowerCase().charAt(i)```.
Please provide more details about what is wrong.

Comment: @Mr. R actually my code works for the small cases, but if there is any capital letter, suppose bncHm it shows "codang" also same result if there is a z. so wondering how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `charCodeAt` to get the code of the letter, you can increment by one, to get the code of the next letter, and you can use `fromCharCode` to get the character, This will work for capital and small characters.

```js
function myf(a){
 let newstr =""

for(i=0; i<=a.split("").length-1; i++){
    let str = a[i];
    let code = str.charCodeAt()
    // if the letter equal to z make it a
    let nextCode = code === 122 ? 97 : code === 90 ? 65 : code + 1
    let nextCharacter = String.fromCharCode(nextCode)
    newstr += nextCharacter
}

 console.log(newstr)
}

myf("bnchmf")  // result: coding
myf("BNCHMF")  // result: CODING
myf("bgddrd") // result: cheese
myf("sdrshmf")// result:testing
myf("zmfkd") // result: angle
```

Comment: what does 122 ? 97 mean? could you please explain ? how are you getting this numbers?

Comment: These are ASCII  codes for letters, 122 = z, 97 = a, 90 = Z, 65 = A, you can find all these codes here. http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html

Answer (score 4):

You could calculate the letter by parsing a character, get the value in a 36 numbers system and add one. To ge the wanted value without carry take the rest of 36 and if zero add ten to get an `'a'` (this was a `'z'` before).

```js
function convert(string) {
    let result = '';
    for (const c of string) {
        result += (((parseInt(c, 36) + 1)  % 36) || 10).toString(36);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(convert("bnchmf"));   // coding
console.log(convert("bgddrd"));  // cheese
console.log(convert("sdrshmf")); // testing
console.log(convert("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")); // bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     // remember capitals
      var obj={};
      for(let itr=0;itr<arg.toString().length;itr++){
       if(arg[itr]==arg[itr].toUpperCase()){
          obj[itr]=true // isUpperCase
       }
        // toLowerCase
         for(let iter=0;iter<String(arg).toLowerCase().split('');iter++){
       // your code
       }
```

The remembered capitals are used to restore uppercase letters before logging the result.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will help you.

```js
const convert = (str) => {
  let result = "";
  for (const char of str) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(
      char.charCodeAt(0) + 1 === 123
        ? 97
        : char.charCodeAt(0) + 1 === 91
        ? 65
        : char.charCodeAt(0) + 1
    );
  }
  console.log(result);
};

convert("XYZ");
convert("bgddrz");
convert("bnchmf");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact challange, but would suggest this:

1. you can add uppercase alphabet in `ltr`
2. I suppose that after letter "z" should be letter "a"
3. don't need to split `a` in each loop

```js
function myf(a){
  const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA"
  let newstr = ""

  for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    let nxt = alphabet.indexOf(a.charAt(i)) + 1
    newstr += alphabet.charAt(nxt)
  }

  console.log(newstr)
}

myf("bnchm")  // result: coding
myf("bgddrd") // result: cheese
myf("sdrshmf")// result:testing
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the question but, it looks like a [Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

You have a string that only contains lowercased letters. You will not be able to match uppercased letters against this string unless you perform a case conversion by:

- Using [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method
- Using ASCII char code trick and incrementing char code of the uppercased letter by 32 to get the corresponding lower cased letter

A good way will be to always perform a check in a single case. That is, irrespective of the user input, you convert the input string to `lowercase` or `uppercase` and then proceed with deciphering it.

Answer (score 0):

### Correcting typo

You simply have a typo in your code. `ltr.charAt(nxtltr)` gives the error *"nxtltr is not defined"*. If you replace it with `str` the decoding seems to work correctly.

Below is a snippet of it working:

```js
function myf(a){
  let ltr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  let newstr = ""

  for(i=0; i<=a.split("").length-1; i++){
    let str = ltr.indexOf(a.charAt(i))+1
    let mystr = ltr.charAt(str)
    newstr += mystr
  }

  console.log(newstr)
}

myf("bnchm")  // result: coding
myf("bgddrd") // result: cheese
myf("sdrshmf")// result:testing
```

When developing it is useful to look at the browser's developer console (usually with *F12* or right-click the website and select *Inspect Element* or similar.